# Java. Calendar. Как представить дату в процентах от заданного отрезка?

Tags: java, дата

У меня такая задача: Есть дата изготовления товара и дата когда он испортится. Мне надо написать такой метод что-бы он определял на сколько процентов `int` дата истекла. То есть на пример товар изготовлен 1 января, испортится 10 января а сейчас 5 января и метод должен вернуть 50 :

```
private int realWork() {
    Calendar createDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 1);
    Calendar expirationDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 10);
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // предположим 2016 / 0 / 5
    long difference = expirationDate.getTimeInMillis() - createDate.getTimeInMillis();
    // а что дальше ума не приложу...
    }
```

Вот такая у меня проблема помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть `differenceOne` – разница между датой изготовления и датой окончания срока годности и `differenceTwo` – разница между датой изготовления и текущей датой.

Тогда искомое число – это отношение `differenceTwo` к `differenceOne` (в долях). Если домножить это отношение на 100, то получите искомое в процентах.

```
private float realWork() {
    Calendar createDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 1);
    Calendar expirationDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 10);
    Calendar currentDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 5);
    long differenceOne = expirationDate.getTimeInMillis() - createDate.getTimeInMillis();
    long differenceTwo = currentDate.getTimeInMillis() - createDate.getTimeInMillis();
    return ((float) differenceTwo/differenceOne) * 100;
}
```

Вам осталось только округлить результат.

Comment: Это круто! Как так быстро!?

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помогли мне.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так:

```
private static int getPercentRatioForCurrentDay(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    if (now.isAfter(end))
        return 0;

    long allDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
    long remainDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, end);

    return (int) (remainDays / (allDays / 100.0));
}
```

Процент высчитывается для текущей даты.

Comment: Это какой-то интересный класс LocalDate. Красивое решение но пока сложновато для меня... Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А как по русски прочитать ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end)? И почему метод вызывается на константе?

Comment: @Павел этот интересный класс - это новый стандарт обработки даты и времени, начиная с Java 8. Так что надо осваивать, несмотря на сложности. В ранних версиях жавы используется jodatime (под влиянием которого  и разработаны новые функции даты-времни в 8 версии)